# Probability of casino winning or losing money

Tags: probability, statistics

Rivers Casino did an audit of all of their blackjack tables and found that the amount of money collected per night by a certain table has a mean of $\$6,000$, a standard deviation of $\$200$, and is approximately normally distributed.

a) What is the probability that a table will collect less than $\$6000$ tomorrow night?

b) What is the probability that a table will collect between $\$5800$ and $\$6200$ tomorrow night?

c) What is the probability that a table will collect less than $\$5800$ tomorrow night?

d) What is the probability that a table will collect between $\$5600$ and $\$5800$ tomorrow night?

e) What is the probability that a table will collect more than $\$6400$ tomorrow night?

Comment: Please add more details. What have you tried? What part are you having trouble with? This is a pretty standard question where you can just plug in values in a formula.

Comment: What have you tried and what resources can you use for these questions?